# Cell was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, key-value-observing

I have a crash I can't seem to figure out how to fix. The crash from crashlytics reports:

> An instance 0x101396e60 of class App.FeedCollectionViewCell was
>   deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.
>   Current observation info:  (
>    Context: 0x0,
>   Property: 0x170447b00> )

Each cell has a `AVPlayer` inside of them. This is our process to refresh the players:

1. Upon going to background, we reset the players and set them to `nil`.
2. Upon returning from background, now inside of foreground method, we create new players and call `tableView.reloadData()`.

It seems the app crashes because of doing `tableView.reloadData()`?

**We are currently using a library so we are not registering/unregistering KVO observers for these players. There is also no where else in the app where we use KVO observers.**

It's hard to reproduce this ourselves but Crashlytics reports it.

**The library we are using is VimVideoPlayer: https://github.com/vimeo/VIMVideoPlayer**

Any thoughts?

Comment: you need deregister in deinit of cell, please post the code where you register the observer

Comment: @ReinierMelian Please read the bold part of my question. Thanks!

Comment: Which library are you using? Is it an open sourced cocoapod or something closed? There may be high chance that there is a bug in the library or that its authors didn't take into account using it with `UITableView`. If it is an open project you can eother open an issue on github or try to find and fix the bug, and contribute to the library via a PR. If its a closed library from a vendor you should try looking through their docs and contacting them, maybe they know a workaround for this and if not, you will have broight it to their attention.

Comment: @Losiowaty Hey thanks for the reply. We are using this library VimVideoPlayer - https://github.com/vimeo/VIMVideoPlayer